# Ruby on Rails - routing to current user's posts path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to show posts that only belongs to current user.
The following is my current approach.

Controller

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.posts;
end
```

View

```
<li><%= link_to "Posts", posts_path %></li>
```

Routes

```
match '/posts',  to: 'posts#index',         via: 'get'
```

I get the following error even though I have posts record under this user id

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#index
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup a nested resource for this.

In your routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

Then in your view you can pass the user to the path like so:

`<li><%= link_to "Posts", user_posts_path(@user) %></li>`

The `posts_controller.rb` index action will already have `@user_id` set if the path was called properly with the `@user`.

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources